# ANDROID CAMERA DOESN'T WORK

Tags: android, android-camera

My android camera when tested on the real device can't take the picture and fire the flash with this kind of code, no errors occured. Why is the reason for that?

```
 public class CameraShooting implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

         Context context;
         Camera camera;
         CameraInfo camerainfo;
         Camera.Parameters paras;
         SurfaceView surfaceview;
         SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;
         PictureCallback picturecallback;

        public CameraShooting (Context context){

           this.context = context;
           }
       public void cameraStart(){
    if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        surfaceview = new SurfaceView(context);
        surfaceholder = surfaceview.getHolder();
        surfaceholder.addCallback(this);

    };      

};

        @Override
         public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}
         @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    int numbersofCamera = camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    int cameraID = 0;
    camerainfo = new CameraInfo();
    for(int i =1; i < numbersofCamera; i++){
        camera.getCameraInfo(i, camerainfo);
            if (camerainfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                cameraID = i;
                camera = Camera.open(i);
                break;
                }
                if(camerainfo.canDisableShutterSound){

                camera.enableShutterSound(true);
                }
                paras = camera.getParameters();
                paras.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);    

                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceholder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                camera.setParameters(paras);
                camera.startPreview();

                camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Picture taken",                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };
    }
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
         private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
             @Override
          public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "picture taken");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        }
   };
  };}
```

Your help is much appreciated!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Xml file : 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />               <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: `no errors occured`. You have several exception caught without log, so possibly you just ignore these errors. Moreover, your `break;` seems out of place. In the case of a front-facing camera, you never call `startPreview`, or `setPreviewDisplay`.

Comment: why "In the case of a front-facing camera, you never call startPreview, or setPreviewDisplay"?

Comment: The break is out of place. The for loop won't get round to the rear facing camera, which is probably the one with the flash.

Comment: @NguyenHoaiThanh : like I said, and like NickT said, because of the `break`. It never calls `takePicture`, either. I think you close the for loop in the wrong place. Format your code, it will be much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's the rear facing camera that has the flash, not the front one. Then have something like

```
for(int i =1; i < numbersofCamera; i++){
        camera.getCameraInfo(i, camerainfo);
            if (camerainfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
               continue; //NOT break;
               cameraID = i;
                camera = Camera.open(i);
            }
    // ... etc, etc

     }
```

.